# How can I call the system default browser to display a webpage **INSIDE** my program

Tags: qt, browser, html, qwidget

I mean just like a webkit widget, so i can insert it into my layout.

Answer (score 0):

use [QWebView](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qwebview.html#details) :

> The QWebView class provides a widget that is used to view and edit web
>   documents. QWebView is the main widget component of the QtWebKit web
>   browsing module.

it's not the default system browser but you can display webpage with it.